# $G$ acts on $\operatorname{Hom}(G,K)$ by conjugation

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-actions

I am working on an example of the Drinfeld Double of the Group Algebra and stumbled upon the book [On Characters of Finite Groups](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-981-10-6878-2.pdf). My issue is with 8.1.1, page 192 of the PDF ([relevant part here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsqGG.jpg)). It says:

> The Group $G$ acts on $\operatorname{Hom}(G,K) = \operatorname{Fun}(G,K)$ the $K$-valued maps from $G$ with conjugation: For $g \in G$ and $\varphi \in \operatorname{Fun}(G,K)$ we set $g.\varphi := g \varphi g^{-1}$, that is $(g.\varphi)(s) := \varphi(g^{-1}sg)$ for all $s \in G$.

For me it seems that there are two different definitions for the action which gets me confused ($(g.\varphi)(s) := \varphi(gsg^{-1})$ and $(g.\varphi)(s) := \varphi(g^{-1}sg)$). I do not think that it is an error in the book as the author states $(g.\varphi)(s) := \varphi(g^{-1}sg)$ again somewhere else.

What is meant with $g.\varphi := g \varphi g^{-1}$?

If I try to check that $(g.\varphi)(s) := \varphi(g^{-1}sg)$ is an action, I encounter a problem:

\begin{align*}
(g.(h.\varphi))(x) &= g. \varphi (h^{-1}xh) = \varphi ( g^{-1}h^{-1}xhg) \\
&= \varphi ((hg)^{-1}xhg) = (hg).\varphi (x)
\end{align*}
which is not $(gh).\varphi(x)$ for all $x \in H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but $\operatorname{Fun}(G,K)$ can be endowed with commuting standard left and right translation actions given by $(g\cdot \varphi)(x)=\varphi(xg)$ and $(\varphi\cdot g)(x)=\varphi(gx)$. Then if these actions are implicit in the notation $g\varphi g^{-1}$, you get the definition Broué gives.

It is indeed an action since
$$
(g.(h.\varphi))(x)=(h.\varphi)(g^{-1}xg)=\varphi(h^{-1}g^{-1}xgh)=\varphi((gh)^{-1}x(gh))=((gh).\varphi)(x).
$$

In the first equality, $g$ is acting on the function $h.\varphi$ first, which is why your calculation came out backwards.

Answer (score 2):

$({}^g({}^h\varphi (s)))={}^h\varphi (g^{-1}sg)=\varphi (h^{-1}g^{-1}sgh)=\varphi ((gh)^{-1}sgh)={}^{gh}\varphi (s)$ would be the right way to do it I think...